# How to maintain user session in the client?

Tags: api, rest, session, authentication

So I have a REST API. I followed [this](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/) tutorial in setting up client authentication. I'm done with that. Now the next part is user authentication. What I have in mind is like this:

1. The client sends the login details to the API.
2. The API validates the username and password and generates a token that is sent back to the client.
3. The client stores the token somewhere and use it for authentication for subsequent requests.

The questions, is this a proper way of maintaining sessions in setups like this? Are there better ways in implementing this? I'm very new to this type of thing so please be elaborate with your answers. Please note that the API is pure REST and client could be anything(eg. Angular, iOS, Android app). So it's not typical in the sense that the front-end is not on the same server as the API.

Comment: If you're not Good at security, you should be using a library. Security is Hard.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that but you would be going off the beaten track of proven security patterns. This probably isn't wise and will give you lots of extra work and headaches.  However, here's one service provider that exposes a REST API and created their own extension of OAuth.  It is similar to what you outlined so I list the steps here to serve as an example but not necessarily recommending you follow:

- Consumer Application collects the User's credentials directly
- Consumer Application concatenates the user name and password with a space and base64 encodes the credentials
- Consumer Application puts the encoded credentials in the body of the request. Credentials must be URL Encoded after they are base64 encoded
- Consumer Application posts them to a designated URI (example: api.com/v1/user/accesstoken)
- This request is signed using OAuth signing requests
- The Service Provider will hand the Consumer Application back an Access Token
- The Consumer Application will access the User's data using the Access Token